# MS SQL / PHP INSERT BUT IF EXIST UPDATE JUST A VALUE +1

Tags: php, sql, insert

I got a Table Named:

`Statistic`

The Columns are:

> city - datedata - counter

The Table is empty with no Data

```
$gotCity = $_GET['city'];
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
$datetime_variable = new DateTime();
$currentdate = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d');
$tsql = "INSERT INTO statistic (city, datedata,) 
      VALUES('".$gotCity."','".$currentdate."') ON DUPLICATE KEY
      UPDATE counter=counter+1";  
$getResults2=sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

The code does not work it does nothing.What i want it to do is trigger php page

(TABLE IS EMPTY HAS NOTHING IN IT)

```
xxxxx.php?city=London (as example)

city       datedata          counter
London     2018-03-21        1
```

Triggering it again

with `xxxxx.php?city=London` on the same day:

update `counter +1` so in the table its:

```
city       datedata          counter
London     2018-03-21        2
```

Trigger it on 2018-03-22 with London and with a new city lets say Dubai it should insert it as a new entry so every city exist just 1 time every day, there is no 2 london on the same day

```
city       datedata          counter
London     2018-03-21        2
London     2018-03-22        1
Dubai      2018-03-22        1
```

UPDATE:
My Code snipped should work i checked it with some other codes that are online but this seems to work only for MySQL not for MsSQL :(

> I set now Index for company,datedata to UNIQUE and counter as PRIMARY
>   KEY

```
INSERT INTO statistic("city", "datedata")
VALUES ("London", 2018-03-21)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "counter"="counter"+1;
```

UPDATE 2:

Changed my Database to MYSQL and the first Code does work now, the "DUPLICATE KEY" query logic does not work on MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know what SQL you are using (MS?? or MySQL). If your SQL syntax is indeed correct then I would suspect that you need to make the city AND date the key/constraint. I.e. you should make the city AND date the key (without seconds/time).

You may also need to set the default value for count as 0 or 1 depending on your logic/requirement.

Trust this helps.

Comment: i think its MSSQL because its a database on Azure. i already have other code running for just updating a value so there is something wrong in the SQL query $tsql = .......

Comment: Tip: Check the field types in the table. Also make sure that your index is unique for City AND date (Y-m-d). If possible print out the $tsql and have a look at it, execute it in phpMyAdmim or something like that.

Also maybe counter is a reserved word in MySQL.

Following is the syntax from MySQL:

INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

Comment: i tried to run a query i got online that should work now, but it does not work manually using it in sqlpro for Mssql (sql gui for macosx) it give me the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. (Line 3)"
and i found out it does not work because its for MySQL but not for MSSql. but still can't find probably working code

Comment: Some tools won't allow non-standard SQL or SQL that it was not programmed to understand (i.e. new features). I still think you need to CHANGE YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE so that the CITY AND DATE are ONE UNIQUE KEY. Please read all the comments I made again. I think you have made ONLY the city as the key, Only city as the key is WRONG, the City AND date, BOTH must be the key, good night.

Comment: no i understand you correctly I've done it already they are both declared as UNIQUE, and the counter is Primary key

Comment: No, you don't understand the COUNTRY AND CITY must be unique together! Your key should be 'London_2018-03-01'. Please think about it. Here is what you can do, create a table with the key as countrydate and field as count.  Your sql will be:INSERT INTO statistic (city_country) 
      VALUES('".$gotCityCounry."') ON DUPLICATE KEY
      UPDATE counter=counter+1". I think you will get it now. How can your counter be primary key? For example, New York can also be 1, right?

Comment: Okay i tried it out like you said, but still it didn't work out and the reason is MSSQL does not support  the "ON DUPLICATE KEY" syntax.
Using the code from my question does work on MYSQL so i just changed MSSQL to MYSQL DB and now my code in question section does work for any other person who will come with these failure, changing to mysql does help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion that it is important to know which database you use, changing it to mysql solved my problem as workaround! :-)